# Flash update breaks the Mindstoms NXT viewer

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

After udating to the lastest version of Flash on my Macbook Pro (OS X 10.7.4) The Mindstorms NXT software that comes in the box no longer displays the build instructions. It does load up, but the build instructions pages are blank.

Is this a known issue, and is there a fix available?

Comment: You may want to contact the LEGO customer service about this, even if they don't have a fix ready at least they'll know about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed using the NXT software version available from http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/nxt-software/ instead of CD that came with the NXT set.